# SAS Not Exporting to Microsoft Access

Tags: sas

I am trying to export a SAS dataset to Microsoft Access using a simple proc export command.  This command use to work but the new computer I'm using is causing some complications.  I now have a 32 bit computer but a 64 bit SAS Enterprise Guide.  Now, when I try to run the code, I'm getting a "ERROR: Failed to connect to the Server" message.  I have already tried swapping out the dbms=access with dbms=accesscs but still get the same message.

```
proc export data= LibFolder.T_test
    
            outtable="t_test"
    
            dbms=access 
    
            replace;
    
   database="C:\To_AccessDB.accdb";
run;
```

Comment: Version of Enterprise Guide does not matter.  It is the version of SAS itself that matters. Are you using Enterprise Guide to connect to SAS running on your new computer? Or some other computer?  Is the computer where SAS is running using Windows?  Do you have 32 or 64 bit version of SAS?  Do you have 32 or 64 bit version of Microsoft Office?

Comment: SAS is 64 bit and Windows is 34 bit

Comment: SAS/Access cannot work with bit mismatch between Office and SAS.  Either get a 32bit verison of SAS.  A 64bit version of Office.  Or otherwise you have to try to figure out how to to get the SAS PCFILES Sever to work so that you can have an 32 bit verison of that which can talk to Office.  https://support.sas.com/kb/43/802.html